# How many ways to pick k integers with fixed sum and product

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

We are given $1\leq S \leq 10^9$ and $1 \leq P \leq 10^9$.
We need to pick $k$ integers $x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k$ (all of which have to be $>1$) such that $\sum_k{x_k}=S$ and $\prod_k{x_k}=P$.

What is a (good) upper-bound for the number of ways to pick those $k$ integers (in the worst case for any $S$, $P$)?

Note that we can assume $k<30$ since having 30 2's will lead to a product of $2^{30}>10^9$.

Comment: Shouldn't limit the problem with the bound $10^9$

Comment: Is $k$ fixed or variable?

Comment: Worst case here means highest?

Comment: $k$ is fixed.
Yes, worst case here means the highest bound accross all $S,P$

Comment: If $k$ is fixed, then you can improve upon the trivial bound of $d_k(P)$ (the number of ways to write $P$ as a product of $k$ integers) by looking at bounds for decomposable form equations; see for example https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertsejh/95-decforms.pdf. Improving on these sorts of bounds is very difficult. It is expected that there is a uniform bound (dependent on $k$ only) for such equations, but this seems far out of reach.

Comment: Is this a Project Euler challenge?

Comment: TeX note: please use `\sum` and `\prod` instead of `\Sigma` and `\Pi`.  Compare, for example, $\sum_k x_k$ `\sum_k x_k` to $\Sigma_k x_k$ `\Sigma_k x_k` and, even more, $\displaystyle\sum_k x_k$ `\displaystyle\sum_k x_k` to $\displaystyle\Sigma_k x_k$ `\displaystyle\Sigma_k x_k`.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Let $B_k({\cal S},{\cal P},{\cal X})$ be a bound for the number of solutions for any $S\leq {\cal S}$, $P\leq {\cal P}$ and ${\cal X} \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_k$.

Using Iverson's bracket notation, we can set $B_1({\cal S},{\cal P},{\cal X}) := \left[\min({\cal S},{\cal P})\geq {\cal X}\right]$ and $B_2({\cal S},{\cal P},{\cal X}) := \left[{\cal S}\geq 2{\cal X} \wedge {\cal P}\geq {\cal X}^2\right]$ (since we have a quadratic equation when $k=2$). Then for $k>2$:
$$B_k({\cal S},{\cal P},{\cal X}) := \sum_{x={\cal X}}^{\lfloor\min({\cal S}/k,{\cal P}^{1/k})\rfloor} B_{k-1}({\cal S}-x,\lfloor {\cal P}/x\rfloor,x),$$
which is easy to implement.

Here are the values $B_k(10^9,10^9,2)$ for $k=1,\dots,30$:

```
[1, 1, 999, 29738, 190560, 496019, 719535, 708082, 540129, 350040, 204993, 112902, 59952, 31160, 15995, 8151, 4136, 2092, 1054, 527, 262, 131, 64, 32, 16, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

It is surely overcounting but still better than nothing.